# How does the typedef struct work syntactically?

Tags: c, typedef

I am new to this, so I apologize if I'm being dense. I'm having trouble understanding how to use `typedef`. Let's say I have the following command:

```
typedef struct {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE] ;
    int nb_mar ;
    } player ;
```

This creates a type called `player` which comprises of a chain of characters, and an `int`, correct?

Now, if we have this line of code:

```
struct set_of_players {
    player T[NB_MAX_JOUEURS] ;
    int nb ;
    };
```

I don't understand what this does? I would assume it creates a variable of type struct `set_of_players`, but what is it called? Usually when I see this kind of command, there's a word after the closed amplesand representing the variables name, but here it has nothing; I don't get it. Would this even work if I haven't done a `typedef struct` for `set_of_players`?

Finally, I have this line of code that I don't understand:

```
typedef struct set_of_players players;
```

I quite honestly have no idea what this even means. I'm assuming this is the `typedef` that I need to make the previous command make sense, but I don't even know what it does.

Again, I'm sorry if I'm looking at this the wrong way, and for the poor formatting. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `struct set_of_players  {....}` is defining a type `struct set_of_players`.

Comment: Using `typedef` with `struct`s allows you to define a variable avoiding the `struct` keyword, i.e.:  `set_of_players players = {"abc", 10};` instead of `struct set_of_players players = {"abc", 10};`

Comment: Thanks for your responses. So, if I'm understanding correctly, both `typedef struct ` and `struct` by itself **create** a type. However, the former helps it helps in the way of legibility? So then, how do I create a variable of type `player`? Do I just declare it as I would any variable? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `typedef` statement allows you to make an alias for the given type.  You can then use either the alias or the original type name to declare a variable of that type.

```
typedef int number;
```

This creates an alias for `int` called `number`.  So the following two statements declare variables of the same type:

```
int num1;
number num2;
```

Now using your example:

```
typedef struct {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE] ;
    int nb_mar ;
} player ;
```

This creates an anonymous struct and gives it the alias `player`.  Because the struct doesn't have name, you can only use the alias to create a variable of that type.

```
struct set_of_players {
    player T[NB_MAX_JOUEURS] ;
    int nb ;
};
```

This creates a struct named `struct set_of_players`, but does not declare a typedef nor does it declare a variable of that type.  Also notice that one of the fields is an array of type `player`, which we defined earlier.  You can later declare a variable of this type as follows:

```
struct set_of_players my_set_var;
```

This line:

```
typedef struct set_of_players players;
```

Creates an alias for `struct set_of_players` called `players`.  In this case the struct is not defined at the same time as the typedef but is defined elsewhere.  So now you can declare a variable of this type like this:

```
players my_set_var;
```

Which is the same as the version using the full struct name.

Comment: Holy moly, thank you so much! Boy did I have a gross misunderstanding of pretty much everything. I have a followup question though: is there a way of making an alias with just `struct`? I'm assuming not, otherwise there'd be no use for `typedef`, no? Thank you.

Comment: @user494405 No, you can't. `struct` is used to create [C structures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm). Whereas `typedef` is used to create type aliases.

Comment: @user494405 `typedef` is specifically for creating a type alias, while `struct` is used for making an aggregate type.  In C (but not C++), the `struct` keyword must be used when declaring a variable of that type, i.e. `struct set_of_players my_set`.

Comment: @user494405 ; If you mean can you typedef an anonymous struct - yes.  `typedef struct { <member-list>} <type-alias> ;` creates a struct that can only be instantiated via the alias as there is no tag.  But it is not clear that that is what you meant.  Best not to tag questions onto answers in comments - post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

### First syntax

```
typedef struct {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE] ;
    int nb_mar ;
    } player ;
```

**This defines an unnamed `struct`. Then, with `typedef`, it creates an alias to this `struct`: `player`.**

You can then declare your `struct` like this:

```
player my_player;
```

It is similar to this syntax:

```
typedef struct s_player {
  char pseudo[MAX_SIZE];
  int nb_mar;
} player;
```

In this second case, since your `struct` has a name, you can declare a `player` like this:

```
player my_player;
struct s_player my_player;
```

---

### Second syntax

```
struct set_of_players {
  player T[NB_MAX_JOUEURS];
  int nb;
};
```

**This defines a structure `struct set_of_players`.** Since you don't have a `typedef`, you'll need to declare a variable of this type like this:

```
struct set_of_players my_set;
```

---

### Third syntax

```
typedef struct set_of_players players;
```

**This defines a type `players` that is an alias to the type `struct set_of_players`.**

Because this creates an alias to `struct set_of_players`, it goes with the second syntax:

```
struct set_of_players {
  player T[NB_MAX_JOUEURS];
  int nb;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's cleared things up.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering you after you have declared this line of code `typedef struct set_of_players players;`

So your code will work like this:-

suppose:-

```
 #define MAX_SIZE 20
 #define NB_MAX_JOUEURS 2
```

Now you can use both the type name like below in our codes:-

```
 typedef struct set_of_players players;
 players PLAYERS;
 strcpy(PLAYERS.T[0].pseudo, "something");
 PLAYERS.T[0].nb_mar = 1;

 struct set_of_players {
      player T[NB_MAX_JOUEURS] ;// reffering to the above example you have created a array of struct `player` and its size is 2
   int nb ;
  };
```

Also you can use the above struct like below:-

```
 struct set_of_players setplayers;
 strcpy(setplayers.T[0].pseudo, "something");
 setplayers.T[0].nb_mar = 1;
```

When you declare a type name to it you don't need to use `struct set_of_players` create a variable instead you will use the type name. That means you have given a specific name to your structure and in your case it was player and players respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is a very simple thing.  Despite its name it does not define new types, but rather defines aliases (names) for existing types.  Its syntax in all cases is:

```
typedef <existing-type> <type-alias>
```

In C a struct type is defined thus:

```
struct <tag> { <member-list> } ;
```

And its its *type* is `struct <tag>` which is more that you might want to type, and might regard as clutter.  So it is a common idiom to create a alias so you do not need preceded the tag with `struct` everywhere.  Hence:

```
typedef struct <tag> { <member-list> } <type-alias> ;
```

and

```
typedef struct <tag> <type-alias> ;
```

Both create an alias for `struct <tag>`, but in the first both the alias and the structure are defined in the same statement, and in the second an existing struct definition is used.

Given such a typedef, instead of declaring a structure variable thus...

```
struct <tag> structure_variable ;
```

... you can use:

```
<type-alias> structure_variable ;
```

which is just syntactic sugar - `typedef` does not affect the code behaviour or code generation.

Note that it is possible to define a typedef using an *anonymous struct* (one with no tag name), so that the structure may only be instantiated using the alias:

```
typedef struct { <member-list> } <type-alias> ;
```

In fact you only ever need a tag name if the structure is *self referring* - i.e. it contains pointers to a struct of its own type (as in a linked list for example), then:

```
typedef struct <tag>
{
    struct <tag>* self ;  // Cannot use <type-alias> here;
                          // it does not exist yet.
    ...
} <type-alias> ;
```

Comment: As a note should you encounter it, in C++ the `typedef struct` idiom is unnecessary, as the `<tag>` on its own is a type-name.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` and `struct` are two different kinds of declarations. `struct` defines a structure type. `typedef` define an alias for an existing type (it doesn't create a new type). They can be combined into a single declaration. Neither creates an object (variable) of the specified type.

```
struct player {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE];
    int nb_mar;
};
```

This is a structure definition. It creates a new type whose name is `struct player`.

```
typedef struct {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE];
    int nb_mar;
} player;
```

The tag in a structure definition is optional. If you omit it, the structure type is anonymous. Here we combine an anonymous structure definition with a typedef, making `player` an alias for the anonymous structure type.

```
typedef struct player {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE];
    int nb_mar;
} player;
```

Here we create a structure type named `struct player` and an alias for that type, `player`.  (The syntax of a structure definition puts the tag immediately after the `struct` keyword; the syntax of a typedef puts the name at the end.)

We can now refer to the type either as `struct player` or as `player`

Here's another way to do the same thing:

```
struct player {
    char pseudo[MAX_SIZE];
    int nb_mar;
};
typedef struct player player;
```

With two separate declarations, we create a new type called `struct player`, and then we use the typedef to define a new name for that type, `player`.

In all these examples, I've used the same identifier for the structure tag and the typedef name. There's no requirement for them to be the same, and there are coding conventions where you might use `struct player_s` or `typedef ... player_t`. But since both names refer to the same type, there's no real reason to use different names. They should at least be related to each other in a simple and obvious way.

Note that a typedef for a structure type is never really necessary. You could just define the struct type without using a typedef, and consistently refer to the type as `struct player`. All the typedef does is define a new name for a type that already has a perfectly good name. (The advantage is that the new name is a single identifier; I personally don't see that as much of an advantage.)

Another point is that you need the structure tag if the structure contains a pointer to its own type:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

You have to use `struct node` in the declaration of `next` because the typedef name isn't visible yet. (There are ways around that using forward declarations, but I won't get into that.)